# loop a var key in a res.json response

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mern

so this is the portion of my code :

```
var roomid= roomIds[i] 
const Availabilitydata = await AvailResponse.json();
    availableroomsArray.push(Availabilitydata);
    
        app.get("/api/availability", (req, res) => {
            res.json({ indicateur: availableroomsArray});});
    }
```

so the variable indicateur looping 3 rooms Ids in an array
so when you visit /api/availability it will print the availibility of the 3 rooms in 2022-03-20 this way

```
{"indicateur":[{"20220320":{"i":1,"p1":"74.00","p2":"78.00","p3":"70.3000","p4":"122.4600"},"20220320"{"i":0,"p1":"74.00","p2":"77.00","p3":"70.3000","p4":"120.8900"},"20220320":{"i":0,"p1":"65.00","p2":"68.00","p3":"61.7500","p4":"106.7600"}}]}
```

and it is working fine .

What i am trying to achieve is displaying the roomId of each room in front of its availability like this :

```
{"1212":[{"20220320":{"i":1,"p1":"74.00","p2":"78.00","p3":"70.3000","p4":"122.4600"}]},
{"1213":[{"20220320"{"i":0,"p1":"74.00","p2":"77.00","p3":"70.3000","p4":"120.8900"}]},
{"1214":[{""20220320":{"i":0,"p1":"65.00","p2":"68.00","p3":"61.7500","p4":"106.7600"}}]}
```

I tried to replace `indicateur` in  `res.json({ indicateur: availableroomsArray});});` by  `roomid` but it will be printed as it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create  an object `var obj = {};` to store (key,value) pairs

```
   obj[roomIds[i]] = Availabilitydata; // key,value pairs object
    availableroomsArray.push(obj);

        app.get("/api/availability", (req, res) => {
            res.json({ availability : availableroomsArray});});
    }
```